# disable downloadButton when no shiny checkboxGroupInput item selected

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

I would like the download button in the below shiny app to become enabled ONLY when at least one check box is selected. Following [this guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25247852/shiny-app-disable-downloadbutton), the below app disables the button upon page load and enables the download button after the user selects a check box. However, if the user then deselects all checkboxes, the button remains enabled. Is there a way to program the app to disable the download button again if the user deselects all checkboxes?

```
library(shiny)
data(iris)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  
  mainPanel(
    fluidRow(checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "iris_species", label = "Select Species", 
        choices = unique(iris$Species))),
    fluidRow(downloadButton("download_bttn" , "Download Artifact"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  observe({
    if(!is.null(input$iris_species)) {
      shinyjs::enable("download_bttn")
    }
  })
  
  output$download_bttn <- downloadHandler(filename = function(){paste0("Artifact -",Sys.Date(),".csv") },
    content = function(file) {
      
      iris_mod <- iris[which(iris$Species %in% input$iris_species),]
      write.csv(iris_mod, file)
   }
  )

  # disable the download button on page load
  shinyjs::disable("download_bttn")  
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `observe`, you need to know to `disable` it as well. You can use an `else` clause with `disable`, or you can just use

```r
  observe({
    shinyjs::toggleState("download_bttn", condition = !is.null(input$iris_species))
  })
```

in place of your current `observe` block.